# Generate a swagger.json file from comments in code

Tags: javascript, swagger, openapi

I am creating documentation for an API written in `node.js`

I have created a `swagger.json` file by hand and I feed it into a `swagger-ui` frontend in order to make pretty API docs.

However, what I would love to be able to do is to generate API docs from code in a similar way to `JSDoc`- by simply marking up my code with comments and then running a command that creates the documentation (in this case a `swagger.json` file) directly from the code.

What is the easiest way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [swagger-jsdoc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger-jsdoc) library:

```js
/**
 * @openapi
 * /:
 *   get:
 *     description: Welcome to swagger-jsdoc!
 *     responses:
 *       200:
 *         description: Returns a mysterious string.
 */
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World!');
});
```

Comment: That looks like it's just Swagger yaml, not JSDocs.